# rails dependent: :destroy works with wrong ID value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

my schema.db

```
  create_table 'pet', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string 'name'
    t.datetime 'created_at', precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table 'user', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string 'name'
    t.references :pet, index: true, foreign_key: { on_delete: :nullify }
    t.datetime 'created_at', precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :pet, foreign_key: :id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

pet model

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

show.erb

```
    <%= link_to t('delete'), user_path(id: @user.id), method: :delete %>
    <%= link_to t('.pet_delete'), pet_path(@auser.pet_id), method: :delete %>
```

user controller

```
  def destroy
    User.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

pet controller

```
  def destroy
    Pet.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

Problem :
if i delete user id 5 with pet id 5,
dependent destroy works well and it deletes (user id 5) & (pet id 5)

if i have user id 5 with pet id nil,
and user id 4 with pet id 5,
when i delete user id 5, user 5 deleted with user4's pet (pet id 5)
so leftover result -> user id 5 delete, user id 4 with nil pet

something is wrong but i can't find what is problem.
dependent destroy can only find same userId and petId in the same time.

i expecting if i delete user id 3 with pet id 1, want to make delete well
i tried change position of dependent destroy(on pet model),
change schema.rb's on_delete nullify to delete but not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specified `id` as a foreign key.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :pet, foreign_key: :id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

You need to specify `user_id` instead:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :pet, foreign_key: :user_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

But, in a simple case like this you don't need to specify foreign key at all. As long as you have a column named `user_id` in `pets` table it will just work, since Rails automatically assumes that the foreign key should be `<model>_id`.

Also, please keep in mind that the foreign key should be added to the **child**, not the **parent**. So, you need to add `user_id` to `pets` table, not `pet_id` to the `users` table.

In the end, your `schema.rb` should look something like this:

```
  create_table 'pet', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string 'name'
    t.datetime 'created_at', precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', precision: 6, null: false
    t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: { on_delete: :nullify } # <== this should be added
  end

  create_table 'user', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string 'name'
    # t.references :pet, index: true, foreign_key: { on_delete: :nullify } <== this should be removed
    t.datetime 'created_at', precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Comment: i appreciate for your support. you save my time. i have a extra question, adding 'foreign_key:' in model makes foreign key column at associated table, not in a model itself?

Comment: @nicecoding521235 yes, foreign key is a property of the associated table. 
It may be confusing in your example, because you have one-to-one relation. But, if you think about a situation where a user has multiple pets it becomes more obvious. Otherwise, you would need to add a database column for each new pet.